# How to fix the version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-conversion

I tried to search in database between two dates but it get error:

> The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

This is my code

```
if (idbox.Text != "")
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dataadabter = new SqlDataAdapter("select name, mil_no,Hodor_date,rotba,enseraf_date,user_hodor,user_enseraf,hodor_time,enseraf_time " +
    "from Hodor_Data where CONVERT(DATETIME,Hodor_date,101)" + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " and mil_no='" + idbox.Text + "'", conn);

    SqlParameter fromdate = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
    fromdate.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    SqlParameter todate = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
    todate.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    dataadabter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromdate);
    dataadabter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(todate);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataadabter.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    conn.Close();
```

`hodor_date` is `nvarchar(50)`

Comment: `SqlDbType.DateTime2` clearly should be changed to something else then. Have you done any research into possibilities? Also why is `hodor_date` a `nvarchar(50)`? Why isn't `idbox.Text` parameterised?

Comment: It always helps if you actually **read the words** in the error message. In this case, it very clearly explains the problem, and the words clearly mean that you need to change to a version of DateTime that are supported in your version of SQL Server. The documentation for your particular version will tell you what datatypes are available to you.

Comment: i don't understand u what i should do ?

Comment: i user sql server 2005

Comment: The non-parameterised idbox.Text is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older version of sql, use `SqlDbType.DateTime` instead as the sql server version does not support DateTime2.

```
...
SqlParameter fromdate = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
fromdate.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
SqlParameter todate = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
...
```

*There are other things in the code that I take issue with (non parameterized member, not using using blocks, nvarchar for date, etc).*

Comment: i use sql-server2005 ... the same erroe

Comment: @Amr - make sure you recompile your code after you make the change and run it again. `SqlDbType.DateTime2` becomes `SqlDbType.DateTime` everywhere you have it in your code. Also any casting you do directly in your sql statement should be to datetime and not datetime2.

Comment: @Amr - so problem fixed. If there is no result you need to analyze the data and the parameters you are sending.

Comment: i tried this code in my home and when i tried it in sql server 2008 it get nothing  where is the wrong ?

Comment: @Amr - If you have 3 records with dates 2016-05-01, 2016-05-02, 2016-05-03 and you do a comparison and pass in starting date 2016-07-01 then you will get nothing back. Syntax might be perfect but there is no data that matches your range. That is what is going on, your where clause excluded all possible data. As I said before you need to check your data and the parameters.